# Not reaching POST data without index.php into REST API

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an API URL /avi and I want POST data into index.php but I can't get the value. If I add index.php with the URL (/avi/index.php) then I can get the POST data. Please help me.
Please check my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you even need a rewrite rule for this? I'd think just a `DirectoryIndex` would be sufficient.

Comment: If your server has [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) set to `On` (which is the default), then mod_dir will automatically externally redirect from `/api` to `/api/` first - and with the browser following that redirect by making a GET request, you lose your POST data. You could turn that off (but take note of the security warning in the documentation, before you do) - or just make sure that you post to `/api/` instead of just `/api` to begin with.

Comment: Please check this video screen of the postman [link](https://d.pr/v/kXGYJZ). I want data without index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in an API of mine.

The reason this happens is because requests to `/api` are by default redirected to `/api/`.

Following that redirect loses your POST data. (In a mobile app I was making that used my API, requests to `/api` would actually fail because my http client was configured to not follow redirects, so beware of that).

The simplest way to fix this is to call directly `/api/`.

<s>You could add a rewrite rule I suppose, if you want to make the url prettier.</s>

@CBroe is right actually, you can't just rewrite.

My other suggestion is, to have each endpoint as an `endpoint.php` file, in you `api` directory or any subdirectory and add a rewrite rule to append `.php` to you API calls. That way calling `/api/endpoint` would go through as `/api/endpoint.php` and run you php file.

Comment: Can you please provide the rewrite rule? @Leonardo Hysesani

Comment: A RewriteRule can't fix this - mod_dir performs its functionality, before mod_rewrite does. The redirect has already happened, _before_ you get a chance to rewrite the request.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and still not working with the rewrite request.